# How long is a RingOut ID supposed to live for?

Tags: ringcentral, ringout

Firstly, ringout is working correctly, it dials two numbers and connects them together successfully.

When I send a POST request to the Ringout REST API endpoint, I get a ringout ID back. I then use this ringout ID and issue a GET request every few seconds to track when both parties have answered there calls. ( I am aware of webhooks, but webhooks don't give me the callee's status)

```
{  
"uri": "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/XXXX/extension/XXXXXX/ringout/XXx";,
  "id": xxx,
  "status": {
    "callStatus": "Success",
    "callerStatus": "Success",
    "calleeStatus": "Success"
  }
}
```

I use this same polling technique to work out when either party has disconnected from the call.

```
{  
"uri": "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/xxxx/extension/xxxx/ringout/xxxx";,
  "id": xxx,
  "status": {
    "callStatus": "CannotReach",
    "callerStatus": "Finished",
    "calleeStatus": "Finished"
  }
}
```

I noticed that the ringout ID only lives for about 30 seconds, after this time when I send a GET request I get this response even though the phone call is still taking place.

```
{  
"errorCode": "CMN-102",
  "message": "Resource for parameter [ringoutId] is not found",
  "errors": [
    {
      "errorCode": "CMN-102",
      "message": "Resource for parameter [ringoutId] is not found",
      "parameterName": "ringoutId"
    }
  ],
  "parameterName": "ringoutId"
}
```

Is this the expected behaviour for a ringout call, does the ID disappear after 30 seconds, even though the call is still active?

Comment: Did my post below answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

This question was also asked in the RingCentral Developer Community, and answered by the Principal Architect for the Platform: https://devcommunity.ringcentral.com/ringcentraldev/topics/how-long-does-a-ringout-id-live-for

Adding a copy of Anton's answer here to save people a click...

> Ringout ID lives until both call legs are established (or canceled).
>   You cannot use this ID to check the status of a call which is already
>   connected to both parties or to cancel already connected call.
>
> In order to monitor status of an established call you should use our
>   presence notifications.